# jquery selector finds but does not work inside live() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I'm having some trouble executing the slideDown() function in the code below. I'm using the live() function because the html was dynamicly added.

When I console log the `elem` var it returns the html, so jquery did finds it but does not execute slideDown() on it. It just doesn't slide down (also no errors and fadeIn() and show() functions don't work either).

Does anyone know what's the problem here? It's really starting to annoy me

```
$(".werkwijze").live('click', function(event) { 

    var num = $(this).attr('id');

    num = new String(num);
    num = num.split('_');

    var elem = $("#uitklap_"+num[2]);

    if(elem.is(':visible')){
        console.log(21);
        elem.slideUp();
    }else{
        console.log(22);
        elem.slideDown();
        //$(".uitklapper").slideUp();

    }

});
```

Comment: jQuery always returns an object, even if nothing is found. Are you sure your element is found ? Check `elem.length` does not equal zero.

Comment: It just works here: http://jsfiddle.net/BWaRk/  Bytheway, you can better use the new [`.on()`](http:/api.jquery.com/on/) function. `.live()` is deperceted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should work fine. Try using `slideToggle` it does the same thing, toggles between show/hide with sliding effect.

```
$(".werkwijze").live('click', function(event) { 

    var num = $(this).attr('id');

    num = new String(num);
    num = num.split('_');

    $("#uitklap_"+num[2]).slideToggle();
});
```

Comment: That doesn't work either. I double checked but when I log `$("#uitklap_"+num[2])` it does return an object with the correct html in it.

The code looks fine to me too, I might need to start looking elsewhere to find the problem.